# Validate positive integers

Tags: java, bean-validation

I want to allow only positive integers for number fields including zero. How can I define this validation using JSR 303 ?
I tried

1. `@Min(value=0 message = "msg1")` - But it allows float values like 1.2.
2. `@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10, message ="msg2")` - It accepts negative values.
3. `@Min(value=0, message = "msg1" )`
   `@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10, message ="msg2")` - It works fine but sometimes both the messages i.e. `msg1` and `msg2` are displayed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using an Integer field?

Comment: @Perception: I am working with legacy application and cannot change it right now.

Comment: Use a custom constraint? - http://nonrepeatable.blogspot.com/2010/05/creating-custom-jsr-303-constraint.html

Comment: @Paul: Dont we have a constraint in JSR to handle this?

Comment: BTW, if you use `hibernate-validator` than you may create custom constraint which combine `@Min` and `@Digits` from 3rd option by using `@ConstraintComposition(AND)`. When you add `@ReportAsSingleViolation` only your custom message will be shown.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin I think that'd be worth of another answer

Comment: Newer versions support @PositiveOrZero for this purpose

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for natural numbers, I think you can use the regex pattern to get the desired output. Something like

`@Pattern(regexp = "[\\s]*[0-9]*[1-9]+",message="msg")`

Comment: but sadly it cannot be applied for integer

Comment: @fmchan for integer, isn't `@Min` the solution? I don't see the point in regexp for an integer

Comment: I want to have only 2 or more values for an integer that won't work using `@Min` or `@Max` right.

Answer (score 62):

Just use the annotation `@Min` in your bean:

```
@Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
private Double value;
```

Comment: what's the "L" mean in that value?

Comment: "L" means explicit Long

Comment: But since it's a Double, it should not be 0.0?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `@Positive` that works for the int and its wrappers too (ie Integer). This also will work for the BigInteger as well.

Comment: `@Positive` considers 0 as an invalid value. https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Positive.html

Comment: You can use it with the @Min annotation and this can provide a solution.

Comment: @VijayNandwana
There is also `@PositiveOrZero`.

https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/PositiveOrZero.html

Answer (score 7):

If you use hibernate-validator then you may create a custom constraint which combines `@Min` and `@Digits` from the 3rd option by using `@ConstraintComposition(AND)`. When you add `@ReportAsSingleViolation`, only a custom message will be shown.

Answer (score 4):

Its better to use range annotation like below for positive numbers

```
@Range(min = 0l, message = "Please select positive numbers Only")
```

For negative numbers

```
@Range(min = -9223372036854775808l, max = 0l, message = "Please select Negative numbers Only")
```

Comment: Why is it better?

Answer (score 4):

Another kind of solution and in my personal opinion cleaner and easier to read.

```
@Positive
@Digits(integer = 5, fraction = 0)
```

Comment: why did you choose 5 digits in your example?

Comment: @Simeon to check the postal code, but you can introduce the number that you want

Answer (score 1):

This is an example code from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41675990/258544 above

```
@Documented
@Min(value=0, message = "add a min msg" )
@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10, message ="add a digit msg")
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface NumberFormatValidator {

    String message() default "invalid number";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

It use Constraint composition  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-compound and `@ReportAsSingleViolation` to avoid display both messages

Answer (score 0):

Change the data time of your field from int to Integer and a message.properties file to set the message

### Example: assuming your fieldName is *myNumericField* and belongs to a class called  *Test*

1. Change the datatype:

   - change *private int myNumericField;*
     to *private Integer myNumericField;*
   - Update getters and setters to use/return Integer
2. Create custom message.properties file.
   This may appear to be more work but it's a more elegant and scalable solution rather than having the messages hardcoded in your annotations

   - Create a *message.properties* file under *resources* directory
   - Edit *messages.properties* and add the following line

   `typeMismatch.Test.myNumericField=Please use integers only`

   Remember to change *Test* and *myNumericField* for your class and field name

   - Edit your Application Context xml file and add the following tags before the <\beans> tag

   `<bean  id="messageSource" 
       class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basenames" value="resources/messages" />
   </bean>`

Answer (score 0):

Using the following combination solved the issue for me:

```
  @NotNull
  @Range(min = 1)
  @JsonProperty("end_range")
  private Integer endRange;
```

Make sure to use Integer class instead of int for @NotNull to work.